# Pagination and too much data for sort()

Tags: mongodb

I'm setting a pagination system, but 
when `$page` is `big(2800)` I get an error:

> too much data for sort() with no index. add an index or specify a
>   smaller limit

My code is the following , using Mongodb Doctrine ODM:

```
$markers = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('ngNearBundle:Hospitals')
    ->findBy(array('author'=>$request->getSession()->get('userId')),array('date'=>'DESC'))
    ->limit(15)
    ->skip(($page-1)*15);
```

Comment: Is there an index on `date`?

Comment: No and it seems it was the problem !

Comment: Indeed MongoDB is limited to 32meg of in memory sort if you don't have an index, a.k.a it must actually sort if you don't give an index

Comment: I have just added an index and it works great ! 
Thanks!